# HornetQ - ConnectionFactory exception when the JMS server and queue is hosted remotely

Tags: jms, jndi, hornetq

I am trying to run the Queue example code that comes with HornetQ 2.2.5 final release.  Path is $INSTALL_ROOT/examples/jms/queue.

This example works fine when I run everything on the localhost.  But when I change the configuration so that the JMS server is on a remote host, I am getting a session error from the HornetQConnectionFactory.  The client finds the JNDI service on the remote host, but fails when it tries to establish a JMS connection.  The following is the error stack.

```
$ ./build.sh runRemote
...
runExample:
     [java] serverProps = -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms256M -Xmx256M -XX:+AggressiveOpts
            -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremot   
         -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/ecm/packages/hornetq-2.2.5.Final/examples/common/config
         /logging.properties
         -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
          -Djava.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces 
     [java] Dec 22, 2011 5:54:42 PM org.hornetq.common.example.HornetQExample run
     [java] INFO: hornetq.example.runServer is false
     [java] Dec 22, 2011 5:54:42 PM org.hornetq.common.example.HornetQExample getContext
     [java] INFO: using server0/client-jndi.properties for jndi
     [java] Dec 22, 2011 5:54:43 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate warn
     [java] WARNING: Tried 1 times to connect. Now giving up on reconnecting it.
     [java] javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
     [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:615)
     [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:121)
     [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:116)
     [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.example.QueueExample.runExample(QueueExample.java:55)
     [java]     at org.hornetq.common.example.HornetQExample.run(HornetQExample.java:76)
     [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.example.QueueExample.main(QueueExample.java:35)
     [java] Caused by: HornetQException[errorCode=2 message=Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
     [java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:619)
     [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:611)
     [java]     ... 5 more
     [java] 
     [java] #####################
     [java] ###    FAILURE!   ###
     [java] #####################
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

The following is the hornetq-jms.xml configuration file hosted on the remote JMS server.

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">
   <!--the connection factory used by the example-->
   <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
      <connectors>
         <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector"/>
      </connectors>
      <entries>
         <entry name="/ConnectionFactory"/>
      </entries>
   </connection-factory>

   <!--the queue used by the example-->
   <queue name="exampleQueue">
      <entry name="/queue/exampleQueue"/>
   </queue>
</configuration>
```

The following is the hornetq-configuration.xml configuration file also on the remote JMS server.

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">

   <!-- Connectors -->

   <connectors>
      <connector name="netty-connector">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:localhost}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5445}"/>
      </connector>
   </connectors>

   <!-- Acceptors -->
   <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>        
         <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:0.0.0.0}"/>

      </acceptor>
   </acceptors>

   <!-- Other config -->

   <security-settings>
      <!--security for example queue-->
      <security-setting match="jms.queue.exampleQueue">
         <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
      </security-setting>
   </security-settings>

</configuration>
```

Any thoughts why the Example does not work when I try to host the queue remotely?

Comment: I have the same problem. Unresolved yet. I think the netty-connector config needs a specific host IP, by which your remote client can contact the HornetQ server inside the JBoss. (e.g. 192.168.1.123, if that's the IP of the machine your JBoss is running on. For other syntax see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7828215/510583 )

Comment: Why your acceptor do not have a <param name="port" value="5445" /> ??

connector is used to "send", acceptor is used to "receive". Your connector points to "localhost" port 5445.